# Bash Scripts to rename file name based on nth occurence

Tags: bash, rename

I have the below file names:

```
file-photo01-dfakdj.jpg
file-photo02-bjkadf.jpg
file-photo03-annunioo.jpg
...
```

How to use `rename` command or other bash command to rename those file names to:

```
file-photo01.jpg
file-photo02.jpg
file-photo03.jpg
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `rename` command,

```
rename 's/-[^-]+\.jpg$/.jpg/' *.jpg
```

**(OR)**

With `bash` one liner,

```
for file in *.jpg; do mv "$file" "${file%-*}.jpg" ; done
```

Instead of `*.jpg` you can specify list of file names which you want to rename.

Comment: `mv -i` seems like a good idea (and maybe `-v` for some verbosity). Also probably worth noting that this is the perl package version of [tag:rename]